# HTML5 and graphic

Tags: php, html, sql, css, flash

I was going to build a Flash application which let users go around and collect resources, (tiles graphics, you go with WASD) and then send data to php that save in a database, but as there are many Security issues with Flash, and it's anyway going to die in the future (dropping support) I ask:

What do I need to do, make a similar features in HTML5, What do I need to know? Where is a good place to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**HTML5Rocks**](http://www.html5rocks.com/) is a collection of demoes. In particular, for complex graphics, you'll probably be using the [`<canvas>` element](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/entanglement.html).

If you prefer one coherent text instead of a lot of single articles, you can also look at [**Dive Into HTML5**](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/canvas.html).

Also, if you want to know all the details, having a look at the [**standard**](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-canvas-element) can't hurt.